# Check if Flask request context is available

Tags: python, logging, flask, werkzeug

I want to log some data from context variables (`request`, `session`) when logging during a Flask request, but use default behavior if not.

I'm using a `try ... except` block in `logging.formatter`. Is there a better way to check for a request context?

```
try:
    record.user = session['user_name']
    record.very_important_data = request.super_secret
except Exception:
    record.user = None
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use [`has_request_context`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.has_request_context) or [`has_app_context`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.has_app_context).

```
if has_request_context():
    # request is active
```

Alternatively, `current_app`, `g`, `request`, and `session` are all instances of `LocalProxy`.  If a proxy is not bound, it will be `False` when treated as a boolean.

```
if request:
    # request is active
```